# How to allow customer to "View Cart" / "Checkout" in PayPal?

Tags: paypal, shopping-cart, checkout

We're setting up a simple website with PayPal. We've implemented a bunch of **Add to Cart** buttons and they're working well.

But we assumed we would also add a **View Cart / Checkout** button at the top, so that the customer can stop shopping and complete his purchases. I know the customer can - in PayPal - finalise/checkout any time he clicks on an **Add to Cart** (so he should do it on his *final* add) but he may not have known at that stage that it *was* his final purchase.

Surely there's some PayPal code we can drop onto our **View Cart / Checkout** button which will take the customer direct to his PayPal checkout?

But the [PayPal page listing button types](https://www.paypal-business.co.uk/merchantservices/set-up-your-payment-solution/adding-payment-buttons.htm) doesn't have a checkout button:

[image]

Note: this question isn't about the button image (we're doing that ourselves), it's about what plumbing to put in behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I see now. It's an option within (actually, right near the end) the process of creating your **Add to Cart** button.

[image]